# How to activate plugins automatically in the theme WordpressMu?

Tags: wordpress

How can I activate plugin using function.php? so when the theme is activated, it will also activate specific plugins. thanks

Comment: Your question is a rather Wordpress-specific and less about PHP issues. You should flag it for moderator attention to get it moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ - you'll likely get quicker advise there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@me Quite Simple

```
  require_once('path../wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
  activate_plugin($plugin_path);    // Activate Plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include() the plugin's main php file, but you may have some problems with some of the plugin's hooks so beware :)